# How to simulate handovers in mininet

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, mininet

### Background

I am setting up a simulation through the network emulator [*Mininet*](http://mininet.org). The goal is to create an environment that simulates the network handovers on an
[airplane that utilizes Low Earth Orbit (LEO) satellite constellations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFmuh.png)

### Problem

To preface, I am a fairly new user to the Mininet environment and a novice python programmer. Learning how to use Mininet has been a bit of a challenge.

Currently, I am trying to write a function that will simulate a handover between *satellite1* and *satellite2* for the router on the airplane (represented in between satellite 1 and 2). It has been decided that it will be done by dropping the links and re-assigning the default gateways.

I'm not quite sure how to translate that into python using the [Mininet API](http://mininet.org/api/hierarchy.html). I was hoping that a "Mininet veteran" could share some helpful advice to steer me in the right direction.